# Show data that is only from a specific quarter

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I need to show the data that is only from the 2nd quarter of any year. I am trying to use to_date in the where clause but it is giving me an error. Not sure what I am doing wrong. (Using Oracle 10g)

Code:

```
SELECT product_name, name
FROM a_product p JOIN a_item i
ON p.product_id=i.product_id
JOIN a_sales_order so ON i.order_id=so.order_id
JOIN a_customer c ON so.customer_id=c.customer_id
WHERE regexp_like(product_name, 'Transducer') AND order_date=to_date(2, 'Q')
```

The AND portion is where I am having trouble, it is giving me a "format code cannot appear in date input format" order_date is the field within the table that I use to find out what sales were done in quarter 2 of any year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the arguments backwards.  You want that to be:

```
AND to_char(order_date, 'Q') = '2'
```

The function `to_char()` (in this context) takes a date and formats it as a string.  What string?  A string with the quarter in it.  You then want to compare it to the value you care about.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, I had tried to_char but was doing it like order_date=to_char(2, 'Q'). I just didn't have the order right.